# Setup of MailHandler.php and Contact.html of Template Monster

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on a template from Template Monster and I can't figure out how to make the Contact us work.
I also find a similar post but it does not resolve my problem i.e.
[How to setup a contact form from a templatemonster template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759851/how-to-setup-a-contact-form-from-a-templatemonster-template-i-purchased)

My MailHandler.php is

```
<?php
$owner_email='something@gmail.com';
//SMTP server settings  
$host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$port = '587';//"465";
$username = 'something';
$password = 'something';

$subject='A message from your site visitor ';
$user_email='';    
$message_body='';
$message_type='html';

$max_file_size=50;//MB 
$file_types='/(doc|docx|txt|pdf|zip|rar)$/';
$error_text='something goes wrong';
$error_text_filesize='File size must be less than';
$error_text_filetype='Failed to upload file. This file type is not allowed. Accepted files types: doc, docx, txt, pdf, zip, rar.';

$private_recaptcha_key='6LeZwukSAAAAACmqrbLmdpvdhC68NLB1c9EA5vzU'; //localhost


$use_recaptcha=isset( $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]) and isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
$use_smtp=($host=='' or $username=='' or $password=='');
$max_file_size*=1048576;

if($owner_email==''){
    die('Attention, recipient e-mail is not set! Please define "owner_email" variable in the MailHanlder.php file.');
}

if(preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
    die('Attention, contact form will not work locally! Please upload your template to a live hosting server.');
}

if($use_recaptcha){
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($private_recaptcha_key,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if (!$resp->is_valid){
        die ('wrong captcha');
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['name']) and $_POST['name'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $subject.=$_POST['name'];}
if(isset($_POST['email']) and $_POST['email'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $user_email=$_POST['email'];}
if(isset($_POST['state']) and $_POST['state'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
if(isset($_POST['phone']) and $_POST['phone'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}   
if(isset($_POST['fax']) and $_POST['fax'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
if(isset($_POST['message']) and $_POST['message'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";}  
if(isset($_POST['stripHTML']) and $_POST['stripHTML']=='true'){$message_body = strip_tags($message_body);$message_type='text';}

try{
include "libmail.php";
$m= new Mail("utf-8");
$m->From($user_email);
$m->To($owner_email);
$m->Subject($subject);
$m->Body($message_body,$message_type);
//$m->log_on(true);

if(isset($_FILES['attachment'])){
    if($_FILES['attachment']['size']>$max_file_size){
        $error_text=$error_text_filesize . ' ' . $max_file_size . 'bytes';
        die($error_text);           
    }else{          
        if(preg_match($file_types,$_FILES['attachment']['name'])){
            $m->Attach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'],'','attachment');
        }else{
            $error_text=$error_text_filetype;
            die($error_text);               
        }
    }       
}
if(!$use_smtp){
    $m->smtp_on( $host, $username, $password, $port);
}

if($m->Send()){
    die('success');
}   

    }catch(Exception $mail){
    die($mail);
}   
?>
```

And the Section from contact.html which is the mail sending layout is

```
<div class="grid_6">
                    <div class="wrap_18">
                        <h2 class="header_2 indent_2">
                            Contact Form
                        </h2>
                        <form id="contact-form">
                            <div class="contact-form-loader"></div>
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="grid_2">
                                        <label class="name">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name:" value=""
                                                   data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters"/>
                                            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                                            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid name.</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid_2">
                                        <label class="email">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:" value=""
                                                   data-constraints="@Required @Email"/>
                                            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                                            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid email.</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid_2">
                                        <label class="phone">
                                            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone:" value=""
                                                   data-constraints="@JustNumbers"/>
                                            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                                            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid phone.</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <label class="message">
                                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message:"
                                              data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)'></textarea>
                                    <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
                                    <span class="error-message">*The message is too short.</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="btn-wrap">
                                    <a class="btn_3" href="#" data-type="reset">clear</a>
                                    <a class="btn_3" href="contacts.html" data-type="submit">send</a>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                            <div class="modal fade response-message">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            You message has been sent! We will be in touch soon.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When i click the submit button an error message shows up i.e.

Error!

```
is_valid){ die ('wrong captcha'); } } if(isset($_POST['name']) and $_POST['name'] != ''){$message_body .= '
Visitor: ' . $_POST['name'] . '
' . "\n" . '
' . "\n"; $subject.=$_POST['name'];} if(isset($_POST['email']) and $_POST['email'] != ''){$message_body .= '
Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '
' . "\n" . '
' . "\n"; $user_email=$_POST['email'];} if(isset($_POST['state']) and $_POST['state'] != ''){$message_body .= '
State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '
' . "\n" . '
' . "\n";} if(isset($_POST['phone']) and $_POST['phone'] != ''){$message_body .= '
Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '
' . "\n" . '
' . "\n";}  if(isset($_POST['fax']) and $_POST['fax'] != ''){$message_body .= '
Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '
' . "\n" . '
' . "\n";} if(isset($_POST['message']) and $_POST['message'] != ''){$message_body .= '
Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '
' . "\n";}  if(isset($_POST['stripHTML']) and $_POST['stripHTML']=='true'){$message_body = strip_tags($message_body);$message_type='text';} try{ include "libmail.php"; $m= new Mail("utf-8"); $m->From($user_email); $m->To($owner_email); $m->Subject($subject); $m->Body($message_body,$message_type); //$m->log_on(true); /* if(isset($_FILES['attachment'])){ if($_FILES['attachment']['size']>$max_file_size){ $error_text=$error_text_filesize . ' ' . $max_file_size . 'bytes'; die($error_text);   }else{  if(preg_match($file_types,$_FILES['attachment']['name'])){ $m->Attach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'],'','attachment'); }else{ $error_text=$error_text_filetype; die($error_text);  } } }*/ if(!$use_smtp){ $m->smtp_on( $host, $username, $password, $port); } if($m->Send()){ die('success'); }   }catch(Exception $mail){ die($mail); }  ?>
```

Comment: It is Contact us form for sending the email

Comment: I meant what happens when you run it but never mind, there is a Mail object in there, where is that defined? $m= new Mail("utf-8");

Comment: I think this is the right method to create Object we don't have to define them separate [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm)

Comment: have you included the Mail class file / set of files required for the script to use the class?

Comment: Yes include "libmail.php"; and require_once('recaptchalib.php');

Comment: Ok, so when you try to send the email using the form, what does it do? Do you get any messages? Does the page refresh?

Comment: @Adsy2010 Yes i an error messege and but it is god damn long. I can send that error by comment

Comment: @Adsy2010 Now its done

Comment: I also tried his link but Nothing happens [ HTML Template Documentation](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/quick-start-guide/website-templates/responsive-website-templates-v1-1/index_en.html#undefined)

Comment: could you please add that error to the bottom of your question please, its difficult to read in comments

Comment: this is where your error lies:     $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($private_recaptcha_key,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if (!$resp->is_valid){
        die ('wrong captcha');
    }

Comment: my thoughts are that is_valid might be a method instead of a variable, try : $resp->is_valid() instead within the brackets there. I'll copy the code properly and check if thats not it

Comment: No its vriable in class ReCaptchaResponse {
        var $is_valid;
        var $error;
}

Comment: can you comment out the if() statement including all lines within the if statement: if($use_recaptcha){ } then see if it works

Comment: Now there is no error but it keeps on loading and loading with a rotating circle on the contact us segment

Comment: sounds like more than 1 error in the code. Ok so your original problem is an issue within the if you disabled. The next problem requires disabling all but the most basic declarations and assignments and introduce them 1 at a time. Try reintroducing just the if and none of the code inside and see if you still are error free. This is going to be a trial and error fix

Comment: Still no luck.it is just rotating and so on